# Yii. Передать данные в подключаемый скрипт

Tags: json, yii, javascript

Передаю во `view` переменную, после чего уже во вьюхе

```
$cs->registerScript('p_data', '
    var json = \''.$p_data.'\';
', CClientScript::POS_HEAD);
```

затем подключается скрипт, в котором эти данные должны использоваться

```
$cs->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/js/stock.js', CClientScript::POS_HEAD);
```

проблема в том, что как ни крути, сначала подключается скрипт файла, потом уже скрипт с кодом и данные в файле, таким образом, не видны. какие есть варианты решения проблемы? заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Вставляйте файл в другое место: `CClientScript::POS_BEGIN` или `CClientScript::POS_END`

Comment: @zhukov-roman Спасибо!